# Conformally-flat

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

**Assume given a smooth manifold $(\mathbb{R}^n, g)$, where the metric is a scaled identity $g = e^{2f}I$.** 
**Is there a way to know if this is *always* a non-positive (sectional) curvature manifold?**

Note this is a parametrized manifold that is locally conformally flat. 
Following *Einstein Manifolds* [Arthur L. Besse], the Ricci tensor (in coordinates), can be shown to be:

$R = -(n-2)(H_f - \nabla f \cdot \nabla f^T ) - \frac{n-2}{n}(\Delta f + \|\nabla f\|^2)I_{n\times n}$

where $H_f$ is the Hessian of $f$.

Then $(\mathbb{R}^n, g)$ is of non-positive (sectional) curvature if $R$ is negative semi-definite.

Comment: You might want to check your formula for $R$, since the right hand side clearly vanishes when $n=2$ even though Riemannian surfaces (which *are* *conformally* flat) are not all flat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by *always* non-positively curved. If you are asking if this metric is non-positively curved for any $f$ then this is false. If you are asking for conditions on $f$ ensuring that  the resulting metric is non-positively curved then there is a general formula:

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and let $\tilde g=e^{2f}g$ be a new metric on $M$. Let $p\in M$ and let  $u,v$ be  orthonormal with respect to $g$ vectors in $T_pM$ and $\sigma$ the 2-plane spanned by them.

Then $e^{2f}\tilde{K}_\sigma  =K_\sigma-[Hess_f(u,u)+Hess_f(v,v)+|\nabla f|^2-\langle \nabla f, u \rangle^2-\langle \nabla f, v \rangle^2]$.

This formula is in Besse btw (Theorem 1.159) but it's written slightly differently there.

In the special case you are interested in $g$ is the canonical metric on $\mathbb R^n$ and hence $\tilde K$ is nonpositive iff $H_f(u,u)+H_f(v,v)+|\nabla f|^2-\langle \nabla f, u \rangle^2-\langle \nabla f, v \rangle^2\ge 0$ for any $p$ and any orthonormal $u$ and $v$ in $T_pM$. Note that for example it's always true if $f$ is convex.

Comment: So, more explicitly, what one requires for nonpositive curvature is that $|\nabla f|^2 + \lambda_1 +\lambda_2 \ge 0$, where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the lowest eigenvalues of the quadratic form $\textrm{Hess}(f) - (d f)^2$. 

Comment: @Robert That's a nice invariant way to state it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is very helpful. 

In the original expression, it is clear that for $n=2$ the Ricci tensor is $0$. 
I don't see this as clearly in your expression:

$H_f(u,u) + H_f(v,v) + |\nabla f|^2 - <\nabla f,u>^2 - <\nabla f,v>^2 \ge 0$

Clearly, the last three terms will vanish if $n=2$, but it seems the sum of Hessians might not. 
I wonder if one of the expressions may be some tweaking. 

Comment: @Guillermozo: The expression you wrote in your question is for **the trace free** part of the Ricci curvature. It is of course identically zero in dimension 2. The full Ricci curvature tensor after a conformal change is $\tilde Ric=Ric-\Delta f\cdot g -(n-2)[Hess(f)-(df)^2+|\nabla f|^2\cdot g]$ which you can get by taking the trace of the sectional curvature formula above.